# Bluring a Java buffered image

Tags: java, filtering, bufferedimage

i want to blur a buffered image in Java, without a special "blurring api".
Now i found this [page](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/blurring.html) and write this code:

```
 public int[][] filter(int[][] matrix)
{
   float[] blurmatrix = {
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
};

   int[][] returnMatrix = new int[matrix.length][matrix[0].length];

   for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            returnMatrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j];
           for(int k=0;k<blurmatrix.length;k++)
           {
               float blurPixel= blurmatrix[k];
               int newPixel= (int) (returnMatrix[i][j]*blurPixel);
               returnMatrix[i][j]= newPixel;
           }
        }
    }
    return returnMatrix;

}
```

the int matrix come from this method:

```
 public int[][] getMatrixOfImage(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    int width = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
    int height = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
    int[][] retrunMatrix = new int[width][height];
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            retrunMatrix[i][j] = bufferedImage.getRGB(i, j);
        }
    }

    return retrunMatrix;
}
```

But it want work, what is wrong?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The proble is, the result is not what it should be.
When i have this blurmatrix:

```
float[] blurmatrix = {
    10.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 50.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 0.111f, 10.111f, 
};
```

i get this result :http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/541/2qw7.png
when i have this blurmatrix:

```
float[] blurmatrix = {
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
    0.111f, 0.111f, 0.111f, 
};
```

the picture is deleted.

Comment: What is "won't work"? Exception? Unexpected result? How does the result look like in contrast to what you expected? ...

Comment: sorry, i have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Your matrix seems wrong. Generally the sum of all numbers in these matrixes is 1. Your matrix will probably make everything white.

Edit: I see you corrected the matrix.

Edit2: There's a lot of wrong with your code.

Your method getMatrixOfImage returns an array of 32-bit RGB or RGBA values.
You multiply these values with filter values. That is incorrect. This sort of multiplication makes values of one color spill into other colors. You need to multiply R, G and B values separately.

Your innermost loop (the one with k index) is completely wrong. You take a pixel and multiply it by 0.111 nine times. What you needed to do is take 3x3 pixel square around each pixel, multiply each pixel by the filter value for that pixel, sum them up and then save them as this pixel.

Another wrong thing is that you're filling pixels from source image into destination one in one by one fashion which won't work since you need adjacent pixels which are not filled yet.

Your function needs to create a new image array with same size as source image.
Then it needs to iterate through the destination image and obtain each pixel such as this:

Take pixels in source image in positions `[x-1][y-1]`, `[x][y-1]`, `[x+1][y-1]`, `[x-1][y]`, `[x][y]`, `[x+1][y]`, `[x-1][y+1]`, `[x][y+1]`, `[x+1][y+1]` and multiply them with filter values (in your case it's 0.111 for each of these), sum them up and save the pixel into the new image.

Take note that you need to do this for each color separately (use binary AND operation and bitshifting to obtain each color value). You also need to consider edges, where `[x-1][y-1]` pixel might be non-existent. You can substitute value 0 or use `[x][y]` for those.

Answer (score 2):

Your not doing the [**convolution**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29#Convolution) correctly. You need to set the pixel at `(i,j)` to be the average of all it's surrounding pixels. That is what the `1/9 = 0.111f` are meant for. A convolution operation would average all the neighbours of a pixel into a single value and set that value of the central pixel:

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i-1, j-1)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i-1, j)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i-1, j+1)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i  , j-1)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i  , j)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i  , j+1)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i+1, j-1)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i+1, j)));
         returnMatrix[i][j] += (int)( 0.111f * get(returnMatrix, i+1, j+1)));
    }
}

int get(int[][]m, int i, int j) {
   if(i >= 0 && i < m.length && j >= 0 && j <= m[i].length) {
       return m[i][j];
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: @UMad Well this will need to be done per R,G and B. It's up to the OP to write the extra loop for different channels. This is how you do convolution of a matrix and how many matrices (of different color components) you need to convolve is up to the user.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm has implemented convloution on image matrix of bufferedImage using kernel.Different kernel can be used for different purpose.

Hope it helps

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;


class psp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
try
{


File input=new File("abc.jpg");
File output=new File("output1.jpg");
        BufferedImage picture1 = ImageIO.read(input);   // original
BufferedImage picture2= new BufferedImage(picture1.getWidth(), picture1.getHeight(),BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);      
        int width  = picture1.getWidth();
        int height = picture1.getHeight();

//int kernel[][]={{-1,-1,-1},{-1,8,-1},{-1,-1,-1}};//for edge detection
float kernel[][]={{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f}};//for blur
//float kernel[][]={{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f},{0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f,0.111f}};
//int kernel[][]={{0,-1,0},{-1,5,-1},{0,-1,0}};//for sharpen

for (int y = 0; y < height ; y++) {//loops for images
for (int x = 0; x < width ; x++) {

int r=0,g=0,b=0;//for kernel
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
try
{
Color c=new Color(picture1.getRGB(x+i-1,y+j-1));//x+i-1,y+j-1 will do exact what we want
 r+=c.getRed()*kernel[i][j];
 b+=c.getBlue()*kernel[i][j];
 g+=c.getGreen()*kernel[i][j];
}catch(Exception e){}

}
}
 r = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, r));
g = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, g));
b = Math.min(255, Math.max(0, b));
Color color = new Color(r, g, b);
picture2.setRGB(x, y, color.getRGB());

}
}




ImageIO.write(picture2,"jpg",output);       
}catch(Exception e){
System.out.println(e);
}}}
```